# ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.logging.StyledTextOutput$Style

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I'm trying to build my android app using Android Studio and I keep getting the Gradle Sync error

Error: Unable to load class 'org.gradle.logging.StyledTextOutput$Style'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Over the course of the past few hours I've restarted gradle, uninstalled it, installed multiple different versions but I cannot seem to get the project to build for the life of me.

Some of my research has said that gradle 3.0.0 has fixed this problem but, I'm currently building using gradle 3.3.

Research sources: 
https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin/issues/123
https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin/issues/124

Comment: try adding more detail like how to reproduce this error or the github issue link that you stated before or any other information that you think might be related to your problem.

Comment: @Killer I added two of the sources that I found from a google search but there's not a whole lot I could find on the topic.

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm having the same issue, I've tried manually installing gradle, invalidating cache and restarting, stop all gradle tasks and restart, restarting the entire computer, disabling all plugins, deleted all dependencies (which should have caused hundreds of other errors but its not even getting to that point), made sure build version and compile version match, sync project with gradle files, Ive been searching for hours now and tried everything i have found and nothing is working :(